# Changing who it is from in mail()

Tags: php

I'm sending myself a text message using PHP `mail()` and it says `FRM: username@myftpaddress.com`. I'm using `number@txt.att.net` to send the text message. How can I change that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change default mailed by : address in php mail()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908058/how-to-change-default-mailed-by-address-in-php-mail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional headers to the mail function, including `from`:

```
$headers  = "From: your@email.com\n";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```