# Setting the "name" of the "sender" of an email

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is supposed to send out an email if a comment is made on a submission where a certain condition is met (subcheck = 1).  It works fairly well.

However, the "name" of the sender that shows up is two 7-digit numbers separated by a dot.  How could I make the name of the sender something else, like no-reply@domain.com for example?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$querye = mysql_query("SELECT subcheck FROM submission WHERE subcheck = '1' AND submissionid = '$submissionid' ");

if (mysql_num_rows($querye) == 1)
{

$email_query = "SELECT email FROM login WHERE username = '$submittor'";
$result = mysql_query($email_query);
if (!$result) {
        trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()." in ".$email_query);
}

if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $mailaddress = $row['email'];
        $queryem = mail($mailaddress, "Someone has commented on your submission 
                        $submission.", $comment, "no-reply@domain.com");
}else{
        // no rows found.
}

}
else
{
//your subcheck is not 1 / nothing was found
}
```

Comment: Multiple duplicates. Among others: [how to change default mailed by : address in php mail()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908058/how-to-change-default-mailed-by-address-in-php-mail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `FROM:` so your code will be like this:

```
mail($mailaddress, "Someone has commented on your submission 
                        $submission.", $comment, "FROM: no-reply@domain.com");
```